# Open new tab and also redirect original tab to new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

On a web form I have an asp:button with the OnClientClick set to some javascript, the script opens a new tab then the code behind the button does a Response.Redirect, leaving the original page open in the original tab.

How can I amend this so that a Response.Redirect also happens on the original tab also? IE new tab opens with booking.aspx as per code below, but original tab CurrentPage.aspx changes to NewPage.aspx?

script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

        function SetTarget() {

            document.forms[0].target = "_blank";

        }

</script>
```

button code-behind:

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("booking.aspx?id=" + lbBooking.Text + "&flag=exists");

        }
```

Comment: In SetTarget function, try window.location.href = 'YourURL''

Comment: In addition to what's in it already?

Comment: Yes, function SetTarget() {

            document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
window.location.href = 'YourURL';
        }

Comment: nice one, thanks.  If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SetTarget() { 
    document.forms[0].target = "_blank"; 
    window.location.href = 'YourURL'; 
}
```